# Injective limited Polynomial problem

Tags: analysis

Find the Polynomial f in two variables with coefficents which are natural numbers, so that this Polynomial is limited on $(\mathbb{N}$ without {0}) x $(\mathbb{N}$ without {0}) injective.

I just cannot find this Polynomial. I would love if some of you could help me and give me some tipps on how to solve this.

I know how the form is

[image]

Comment: See [Is There An Injective Cubic Polynomial Z^2 →Z](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073961/is-there-an-injective-cubic-polynomial-mathbb-z2-rightarrow-mathbb-z) for an explicit example of degree 4.