# Examples of polynomial injections $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, soft-question, natural-numbers

I've seen that there are polynomial bijections $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N},$ for example $f(m,n)=\frac{1}{2}(n+m)(n+m-1)+m.$ I'm looking for more examples of injective polynomials from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}.$ Are these common? Are there simple examples that are easy to prove injective?

Also, I should clarify that I am looking for an example that is fundamentally different than the example I gave, not just modifications of it. Preferably there would be a simple explanation of why this example was injective.

Comment: If your given $f$ is a bijection (haven't checked but I trust), just add a strictly positive natural constant $c \in \mathbb N^+$ to $f$ and you are done

Comment: They probably put it in because you are looking for a specific type of function (injective nonsurjective), which is a set theoretic question. I don't know if the tag is needed or not though. @subrosar

Comment: Surjective is fine actually. It just doesn't have to be surjective. I changed the wording to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: I see, that edit is more clear

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Is There An Injective Cubic Polynomial $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow \mathbb Z\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073961/is-there-an-injective-cubic-polynomial-mathbb-z2-rightarrow-mathbb-z)

Comment: Can you define "fundamentally different" precisely?

Comment: @GregMartin No, I can't. That's why I added the soft-question tag. I guess I'm trying to find a general technique for proving injectivity of various polynomials.

Answer (score 11):

It's easy to construct injective polynomials from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$: any increasing polynomial will do, for example, and thus any (nonzero) polynomial with nonnegative coefficients will do.

This observation might seem irrelevant, but note that if $g_1,g_2,h\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ are injective polynomials, then
$$
h\Big( f\big( g_1(m), g_2(n) \big) \Big)
$$
(where $f$ is the polynomial in the OP) is an injective polynomial from $\Bbb N^2$ to $\Bbb N$. One can generate a huge number of examples this way.

Comment: (+1) Extremely clever! And much easier than my idea, haha.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's not quite what I was looking for since these are all essentially the same example. I will edit my question to clarify what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently there is such an injection:

$$
(3x^2 + x + 1) + (3x^2 + x + 1 + 3y^2 + y + 1)^2
$$

I found this in a comment at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392283/cubic-function-mathbbz2-to-mathbbz-cannot-be-injective) MO question, and they also link [this article](http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Favorite-Problem_A07_HCMR.pdf), which provides a wealth of information on a related problem (finding polynomial injections $\mathbb{Z}^4 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$), and thus, by plugging in $f(x,x,y,y)$, on this problem.

As an aside, it's [well known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320323/integer-valued-polynomials-over-several-variables) that every integer polynomial $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ can be written as a linear combination of the form

$$
p(x,y) = \sum a_{ij} \binom{x}{i} \binom{y}{j}.
$$

I don't have the time to come up with anything right now, but it seems reasonable that you could play around with this representation in order to force injectivity.

---

I hope this helps ^_^